# How do we handle questions that relate to fitness and nutrition?

Tags: discussion, scope

How should we handle questions that relate to the [fitness and nutrition SE](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/faq)?

There are some grey areas that exist currently. One specifically (recently):

- [Swimming and respiratory infections](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/47/swimming-and-respiratory-infections)

Where do we draw the line between fitness and nutrition?

Comment: your questions are regarding pro sports trivia.  According to the faq the site is for participants, not fans.

Answer (score 1):

They should be closed as off topic and migrated there. There is no reason for us to duplicate that part of their scope.

Comment: I agree that questions that that relate to fitness and nutrition but don't fit our site, they should be migrated (although there's no need to close... that's handled by the migration.) However, I do not believe the question linked is off topic for our site.

Comment: @corsiKa while we are in beta (before migration paths are established) only diamonds can migrate.

Comment: the point is that you still need to flag it to get diamond attention. There's no need to take two actions when one will be overwritten by another very shortly.

Answer (score 1):

Migrate them to Fitness if they're within the scope outlined in the [faq](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/faq).

If a question is not on-topic for Fitness, close them on Sports as off-topic.